# Assigning result of typeid to a variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rtti, typeid

I'm trying to figure out how to use `typeid` with Microsoft C++ 2015. The example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec.aspx works as-is, but when I add an apparently innocuous extra line, the compiler gives an error.

```
// compile with: /GR /EHsc
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo.h>

class Base {
public:
   virtual void vvfunc() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {};

using namespace std;
int main() {
   Derived* pd = new Derived;
   Base* pb = pd;
   cout << typeid( pb ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Base *"
   cout << typeid( *pb ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived"
   cout << typeid( pd ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived *"
   cout << typeid( *pd ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived"
   auto t = typeid(pb);
}
```

The last line, `auto t = typeid(pb);`, is the one I added, and the error is

```
a.cpp(20): error C2248: 'type_info::type_info': cannot access private member declared in class 'type_info'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\vcruntime_typeinfo.h(104): note: see declaration of 'type_info::type_info'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\vcruntime_typeinfo.h(63): note: see declaration of 'type_info'
```

I would be less surprised if the whole thing had failed, but I don't see how the rest could work if that last line doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot create your own `std::type_info` objects. Such objects can only arise as the value of a `typeid` expression.

Comment: This works `const std::type_info& t = typeid(pb);` I'd imagine though that `auto` should be smart to figure this out, but it isn't. (using g++-4.9)

Comment: According to [std::type_info - cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) is the type_info class neither CopyConstructible nor CopyAssignable.

Comment: @bendervader: WTF? `auto` does template-style argument deduction and always produces an object type; you need to say `auto&` if you want a reference.

Comment: @KerrekSB on gcc, I've tried both const auto& and auto& neither worked!

Comment: My bad... I'll take this back.. I had -std=c++11 not enabled! auto& works with -std=c++11 or -std=c++14

Comment: @bendervader: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/vsWaLW).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, it's just because `auto` tries to copy the referenced object, which can't be done here. It works if you instead say `auto&`.